# Compilation failed: unknown property name after \P or \p

Tags: php, regex, pdo, sqlite, preg-match

Hi I want to match a string:
`"\par hello \par world"`

Against my regexp pattern -> `\\par`

However, I get a `Compilation failed: unknown property name after \P or \p`

I believe my regexp rule is treated as a unicode character property. How do I escape it and run the pattern as it is?

I am including it in a PDO function like so.

```
function sqlite_regExp($sql,$db)
{
    if($db->sqliteCreateFunction("regexp", "preg_match", 2) === FALSE) exit("Failed creating function!");
    if($res = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll()){ return $res; }
    else return false;
}
```

I am calling the function like so

```
sqlite_regExp("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE REGEXP('/\\par/',column) ",$db)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need 3 backslahes `\\\`. Check this example:

```
$string = "\par hello \par world";
$pattern = '/\\\par/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

You can find more info in the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

You have updated the question, I see you aren't using `preg_match` you are using the SQL `REGEXP` function. However, the SQL function should work with `\\\` as well.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ I can't mark it yet. I believe you know SO timeouts lol when marking answers

Comment: @bman, Sorry about that. I've never asked a question on here.

Comment: +1 You have any idea why the patten doesn't work in javascript?

Comment: @raam86 Can investigate

Comment: @hek2mgl I just created my own function which utilizes preg_match in the application and then provide the callback link to the SqLite driver. So this uses preg_match and absolutely works.

Comment: Seems like javascript doesn't record the `\\`

Comment: @raam86 In js this works: `console.info(("\par hello \par world").match(/\par/));`  I guess that is because the js regexp engine do no support the `\p` escape sequence